# How to close WCF service in MVC C# (Umbraco Api controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller, umbraco

How do I close my wcf service in my Api controller
My WCF service object have no close method !

The program works as it should.

```
 private readonly ICarWebServices Service


        public CarBookingApiController(ICarWebServices Service)  // Injecting 
        {
            this.Service = Service;    
        }





        public IHttpActionResult GetAvaliableCars(string userId)
        {
            try
            {
              List<Cars> cars = Service.GetCars(userId).ToList();

           // Service.Close() ?????????????????????? 

            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }
            return Ok<List<Cars>>(cars);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I always create a service client. If the call is succesfull use "client.Close()" to close the service, if the call fails you should use "client.Abort()". See the example below. In your case you should save the injected service in a variable that you can either close or abort.

```
    NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
    netTcpBinding.Name = "NetTcpBinding_IYourService";

    string remoteUrlAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:24888/YourService";
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(remoteUrlAddress);

    List<Message> lstMessages = new List<Message>() { };
    YourServiceClient client = new YourServiceClient(netTcpBinding, endpointAddress);            
    try
    {
        lstMessages = client.GetAllMessages();
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (FaultException<EntityFrameworkFault> faultException)
    {
        var errorText = constructEFErrorText(faultException);
        client.Abort();
    }
    return lstMessages;
```